# 10 second boot loop seemingly caused by gpu

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

New build worked fine on intergrated graphics but after installing new graphics card, it started turning off every 10 seconds even after I took it out.

I don't get a display at all.

I have replaced fan and paste.

I have also reset the BIOS by removing the CMOS battery multiple times.

I have read multiple questions about people having the same problems but I am starting to get desperate.
Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Oh it is more like 20 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Is the whole build new (Every component)? I'm making a lot of assumptions here just based on likeliness so anything you can clarify would help. (parts, OS etc.).
I've had that issue while a Power Supply Unit was dying and unable to power the card. Another possibility is the seating of the card but guessing by your level of understanding you likely have checked things like this. To check the PSU you can of course try using a multi meter on the outbound PCI-E wires, if the card is externally powered which it likely is. If not, check the ATX connector http://www.smpspowersupply.com/connectors-pinouts.htmlis a good layout of ATX voltages to check for use the positive on the colored plugs, negative on the COM (any will do). Also check the CPU power connector (a 4, 6, or 8 pin plug or any combination of multiples of those depending on the board and chip set, you likely know this).

Since you are desperate, I've had issues with seating... but not a boot-loop. I'm actually a Software guy by trade so of course my mind is going that way and you've reset BIOS and CMOS. so my other thought would be graphics drivers. Did it ever work for a period long enough to get into the OS with the card? Because that would be my next try is a combing of the BIOS settings. Usually default BIOS is enough to get you up and running but now and then you will find a configuration of parts in which one is not setup correctly in the BIOS. I also find this unlikely if integrated graphics is working.

I would check your drivers without the card, get them loaded up and do not rely on the OS to get them for you...another question: -which version or OS are you using? Then try the PSU if you have a mutli-meter. Even a cheap one is enough for this testing. Report back please what you find.

Comment: I was using linux and when it did work I didn't get round to changing the BIOS.

Comment: New ssd, new CPU fan, new case, graphics card GT 730 second hand but recently tested and working. The psu is new and is 550w, more than enough to power the components. The gigabyte motherboard is from China so a bit fishy. The CPU is second hand from eBay i5 2400. Btw intergrated graphics stopped working after taking out the gpu. On one or two attempts it managed to reach motherboard specs screen but not bios

Comment: If it was a cpu problem would the computer be able to boot to this screen http://i.imgur.com/ZrTST.jpg

Comment: My Apologies George, I didn't have notifications enabled and do not visit Superuser often enough it seems. I hope that you found your answer?